# Create 100% stacked bar chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, bar-chart, stacked-chart

I need to generate a 100% stacked bar chart, including the % of the distribution (with no decimals) or the number of observations.

My dataset looks like this:

[image]

I need to generate a different one that counts the amount of actives and lates per month:

[image]

And then use this second dataframe to generate my 100% stacked bar chart (should look something like this)

[image]

Does anybody have an easy way of doing this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 10):

You can try `value_counts()` with normalize:

```
(df.groupby('Date')['Status'].value_counts(normalize=True)
   .unstack('Status').plot.bar(stacked=True)
)
```

Comment: Hey !! Thank you very much. One additional question. The chart looks perfect, but is there an easy way to adapt the structure of it? Change colors, the location of the label, modify the y axe to have percentange values, etc

Answer (score 6):

You can use the code below to generate the following chart. Please also consider reading the answer till the end where I explain why a horizontal bar chart may be better.

[image]

My dataset looks like this:

|  | thermal_sensation_round | thermal_preference |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2 | cooler |
| 1 | 2 | cooler |
| 2 | 0 | no change |
| 3 | 0 | no change |
| 4 | 1 | warmer |

I used the following code to generate the plot. In the code I am doing the following steps:

1. grouping the data, counting the entries, and normalizing them
2. plotting the data using Pandas' function `.plot.bar(stacked=True)`
3. placing the legend at the top
4. using the `for` loop to add the formatted text to the chart. Please note that I am not printing the percentage if it is lower than 10%, you can change that.
5. using `tight_layout()` to center the image.

```py
    x_var, y_var = "thermal_sensation_round", "thermal_preference"
    df_grouped = df.groupby(x_var)[y_var].value_counts(normalize=True).unstack(y_var)
    df_grouped.plot.bar(stacked=True)
    plt.legend(
        bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, 1.02),
        loc="lower center",
        borderaxespad=0,
        frameon=False,
        ncol=3,
    )
    for ix, row in df_grouped.reset_index(drop=True).iterrows():
        cumulative = 0
        for element in row:
            if element == element and element > 0.1:
                plt.text(
                    ix,
                    cumulative + element / 2,
                    f"{int(element * 100)} %",
                    va="center",
                    ha="center",
                )
            cumulative += element
    plt.tight_layout()
```

### Horizontal stacked bar plot

Using a horizontal bar plot is a better idea since it is going to be easier to read the percentages. See example below.

[image]

To do that is very simple, you just need to replace the `bar` function with `barh`. Please note that you will need to invert the x and y coordinates in the text function. Please find the code below.

```py
    x_var, y_var = "thermal_sensation_round", "thermal_preference"
    df_grouped = df.groupby(x_var)[y_var].value_counts(normalize=True).unstack(y_var)
    df_grouped.plot.barh(stacked=True)
    plt.legend(
        bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, 1.02),
        loc="lower center",
        borderaxespad=0,
        frameon=False,
        ncol=3,
    )
    for ix, row in df_grouped.reset_index(drop=True).iterrows():
        print(ix, row)
        cumulative = 0
        for element in row:
            if element == element and element > 0.1:
                plt.text(
                    cumulative + element / 2,
                    ix,
                    f"{int(element * 100)} %",
                    va="center",
                    ha="center",
                )
            cumulative += element
    plt.tight_layout()
```

Comment: If a bar has a missing category, the label will have a `NaN` and you'll get an error. I suggest checking if `element` is not a `NaN` (`if element == element`) just before you check `if element > 0.1`

Answer (score 0):

[Quang Hoang's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64754935/948768) works great. However, addressing [Augustina's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64754905/create-100-stacked-bar-chart#comment114495071_64754935) on how to further modify the plot:

The way I do it, is by using [axes (`ax`)](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/axes_api.html). First, you create your `fig` and `ax`:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=[10, 5])
```

Then, you perform your grouping:

```
x = 'Date'
y = 'Status'
df_grouped = df.groupby(x)[y].value_counts(normalize=True).unstack(y)
```

After that, you generate your plot. Notice that we define in which `ax` to plot by specifying `ax=ax`. Moreover, see how we can define the [colormap](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html) already here (remember that you need to `from matplotlib import cm` beforehand, though) or the column width.

```
df_grouped.plot.bar(stacked=True, cmap=cm.get_cmap('viridis'), width=0.75, ax=ax)
```

After that, you can use `ax` to do all the adjustments that you want. For instance add a legend...

```
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.04, 0.95), title='Thermal Preference', loc="upper left", frameon=False)
```

...set your `xlabel`...

```
ax.set_xlabel("Date")
```

...and so on and so forth. Of course, on top of that, you can add the labels as suggested by [Federico](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72727586/948768). However, to keep it consistent, I would replace `plt.text` with `ax.text`.